# Making simple android games without coding experience

Tags: android-emulator

I'm not a programmer but my hobby is being a puzzle game developer, how do I make android games without coding?

Comment: You'll need to learn to code. This isn't the platform for such open ended questions though.

Answer (score 0):

GameMaker allows you to create games for mobile using graphic interface (Drag & drop).
Anyway, sooner or later it will be necessary to write some scripts to have full control of your app, sorry to say that but you can't totally escape from it.

Comment: So you mean it's impossible?

Comment: No: you can create a game without coding, but hardly you will have the full control you would have coding. In other words, you'll have to adapt to the rules of your codeless app-developing program